# error C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, nested, typename

I am trying the following in MSV2010

```
namespace statismo {
template<>
struct RepresenterTraits<itk::Image<itk::Vector<float, 3u>, 3u> > {

    typedef itk::Image<itk::Vector<float, 3u>, 3u> VectorImageType;
    typedef VectorImageType::Pointer DatasetPointerType;
    typedef VectorImageType::Pointer DatasetConstPointerType;
    typedef typename VectorImageType::PointType PointType;
    typedef typename VectorImageType::PixelType ValueType;
};
```

I am getting the following error:

error C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration

An help in a workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
namespace statismo {
template<>
struct RepresenterTraits<itk::Image<itk::Vector<float, 3u>, 3u> > {

    // bla

    typedef typename VectorImageType::PointType PointType;
            ^^^^^^^^

    typedef typename VectorImageType::PixelType ValueType;
            ^^^^^^^^
};
```

Your `typename` keywords are placed inside the explicit specalization of `RepresenterTraits<T>` for `itk::Image<itk::Vector<float, 3u>, 3u>`. However, this is a regular class, not a class template. This means that `VectorImageType` is not a **dependent name** and the compiler knows that `PixelType` is a nested type. That's why it's not allowed to use `typename`. See als [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords?rq=1).

Note that in C++11, this restriction has been lifted, and the use of `typename` is **allowed but not required** in non-template contexts. See e.g. this example

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct V 
{ 
    typedef T type; 
};

template<class T>
struct S
{
    // typename required in C++98/C++11
    typedef typename V<T>::type type;    
};

template<>
struct S<int>
{
    // typename not allowed in C++98, allowed in C++11
    // accepted by g++/Clang in C++98 mode as well (not by MSVC2010)
    typedef typename V<int>::type type;    
};

struct R
{
    // typename not allowed in C++98, allowed in C++11
    // accepted by g++ in C++98 mode as well (not by Clang/MSVC2010)
    typedef typename V<int>::type type;    
};

int main()
{
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbceb7bb7662aec2) (Just play with the g++/clang and std=c++98 / std=c++11 command line options).

Comment: Thanks a lot man. That makes it clear although its not my code and I am not altogether clear on what I can do as a quick workaround

Comment: @TinasheMutsvangwa glad to have been of help!

Comment: @TinasheMutsvangwa The quick workaround would be to remove the typename in those two last typedefs. Although it's not your code, is there anything preventing you from editing it ?

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan: I can edit the code but I am not sure how it affects the rest. I have tried your advise and there are no compilation errors but I am still wondering what the difference will be in the execution